# Main difference between tr (translate) to sed and awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, utilities, tr

AFAIC both `sed` and `awk` are general purpose text processing utilities with whom a user can get quite similar results, in a slightly different syntax:

With both, a user could add, replace/translate and delete content in a file.

What is the main difference between these two general purpose text processing utilities and the `tr` text processing utility?

I assume that `tr`'s functionality is included in both `sed` and `awk` so it is just narrowed to the specific context of **replacing** one string in another, but I'm not sure I'm accurate here or **translating** it to another.

Comment: they ARE different, by no accident

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, `tr` is a "simple" tool compared to `awk` and `sed`, and both `awk` and `sed` can easily mimic *most* of its basic behaviour, but neither of `sed` or `awk` has "`tr` built in" in the sense that there is some single thing in them that *exactly* does all the things that `tr` does.

`tr` works on characters, not strings, and converts characters from one set to characters in another (as in `tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'` to lowercase input). Its name is short for "translate" or "transliterate".

It does have some nice features, like being able to delete multiple consecutive characters that are the same, which may be a bit fiddly to implement with a single `sed` expression.

For example,

```
tr -s '\n'
```

will squeeze all consecutive newlines from the input into single newlines.

The `tr` utility also does not care how long a line is, whereas `sed` will try to read a complete line in memory before operating on it (likewise, `awk` would try to read a whole record before processing it) which could be an issue in some degenerate cases where all the data is on a several gigabyte long "line".

To characterize the three tools crudely:

- `tr` works on characters (changes or deletes them).
- `sed` works on lines (modifies words or other parts of lines, or inserts or deletes lines).
- `awk` works on records with fields (by default, whitespace-separated fields on a line, but this may be changed by setting `FS` and `RS`).

Answer (score 9):

[`sed` has a `y` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03) that is analogous to [`tr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html):

> **y**/*string1*/*string2*/
>
> Replace all occurrences of characters in *string1* with the corresponding characters in *string2*.

```
$ echo 'a big cat' | sed -e 'y/abc/def/'
d eig fdt
```

`y` does not support character ranges `a-z` or classes `[:alpha:]` [like `tr` does](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html), nor the complement modes `-c` and `-C`. Deletion (`-d`) is possible with `s//`, as is replacing runs with single characters (`-s`). As in all of `sed` it's fundamentally line-oriented. `y` is sometimes useful in the middle of a longer `sed` script, but `tr` likely does a better job if that's all you're doing.

`awk` has no equivalent to `tr`'s base functionality, though you could of course replace characters one at a time. The awk language is quite general and you can write loops and conditionals sufficient to implement any transformation you want if you're motivated enough. If you were even more motivated you could probably manage that in `sed` too. The tools are not really equivalent in any sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo ooops not good | tr oops nice
iice nit giid
$  echo oops not good | sed 's/oops/nice/'
nice not good
```

tr translate character by character, not word by word, so it will change all such characters, not only characters that have this exact sequence.

Comment: very usefull example. info tr helps to understand